# Laravel Rules Validation - Only another field has a value

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

```
<input type="checkbox" name="grievance_discipline" value="checked">
<select name="grievance_type">
<option value="_none" selected>- Select One</option>
<option value="suspension">Suspension</option>
</select>

<?php

$this->validate($request,[
  'grievance_type' => 'required_if:grievance_discipline, checked|not_in:_none',
]);

?>
```

The trouble I am running in to, is telling Laravel to ONLY use a particular validation rule if another field has a value.

In the example, the discipline_type field (a select list), is required IF grievance_discipline is checked.

The default select option for the select list is - Select One - with the value of _none. In the validation rules, _none should be thrown out, but it should ONLY validate on it if the grievance_discipline checkbox has value 'checked'.

Could anybody help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting the first option as disabled so the user are forced to pick a value or not submitting a value, hence gracefully fail your validation check. Also, use `required_with` instead of `required_if` to check if another value exist or not.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="grievance_discipline" value="checked">
  <select name="grievance_type">
  <option disabled selected value>- Select One</option>
  <option value="suspension">Suspension</option>
</select>
```

Then in the PHP, do

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'grievance_type' => 'required_with:grievance_discipline'
]);
```